# What is the difference between the serializer virtualProperty and the accessor?

Tags: php, symfony, serialization, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

Per the Serializer [virtualProperty](https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#virtualproperty) documentation

> Note: This only works for serialization and is completely ignored
>   during deserialization.

Other than this limitation, what is the difference between using a [virtualProperty](https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#virtualproperty) and an [accessor](https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#accessor)?

If nothing, why would one want to use it, as the [accessor](https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#accessor) does not have this limitation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best explanations have a concrete example for illustrational purposes. Therefore I'll try to give an example for using both `virtualProperty` and `accessor` to show their differences.

We have an entity `Person`, it has many different properties. One of them is `birthdate`. Let's see the example:

```
class Person
{
    /**
     * @Accessor(getter="getFormattedBirthdate", setter="setBirthdate")
     */
    private $birthdate;

    public function setBirthdate(\DateTimeInterface $birthdate): self
    {
        $this->birthdate = $birthdate;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getBirthdate(): \DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->birthdate;
    }

    public function getFormattedBirthdate(): string
    {
        return $this->birthdate->format('j F Y');
    }

    /**
     * @VirtualProperty()
     */
    public function getAge(): int
    {
        $today = new \DateTime('today');
        $age = $today->diff($this->birthdate);

        return $age->y;
    }
}
```

We use the **Accessor** to specify which getter and setter method will be used during serialization and deserialization respectively. Per default `getBirthdate` and `setBirthdate` would have been used. We'd like however to use `getFormattedBirthdate` for serialization.

The **VirtualProperty** helps us to display the calculated age. It will be used during serialization. Because it's not a real property, it has no setter and it makes no sense to deserialize it.

I hope the example helps to understand the difference between **Accessor** and **VirtualProperty**.

Comment: Yes, best explanations have a concrete example for illustrational purposes.   Great answer.  Thank you